# Add a new section-like level, which isn't subordinated by any other counters

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Is possible to set up a doc structure level `newlevel`, which is not subordinated by any other counters like `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, etc., that is, when the else sec counter is added 1, the new level counter does not change. So we get a document like this:

```
section 1: the first section

subsection 1.1: the 1st subsection of the fist section

subsection 1.2: the 2nd subsection of the fist section

newlevel 1: I

subsection 1.3: the 3rd subsection of the fist section

newlevel 2: Have

section 2: the second subsection of the fist section

newlevel 3: A

subsection 2.1: the 1st subsection of the second section

subsection 2.2: the 2nd subsection of the second section

subsection 2.3: the 3rd subsection of the second section

newlevel 4: Dream
```

The most essential reason why I want to implement these is I can get display newlevel's label and title in both TOC and Header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The counters of subsection etc are only reset when the section counters is set because they are defined this way:

```
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
```

So simply define your newlevel so that uses an independent counter, and then use \@startsection:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{newlevel}
\newcommand\newlevel{\@startsection {newlevel}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\color{blue}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\newlevelmark[1]{}
\begin{document}
\section{a}
\subsection{b}
\newlevel{I}

\newlevel{have}
\section{b}
\newlevel{a}

\subsection{c}
\newlevel{dream}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @U.F. Thanks. But even if I add a line `\pagestyle{headings}` in forearea (and add some blindtexts), I couldn't get a newlevel's title in header --- there's the section label and title, while I want the newlevel's label and title.

Comment: You will have to redefine `\newlevelmark` and perhaps `\sectionmark` depending on your needs. E.g. `\renewcommand\newlevelmark[1]{\markright{My new title: \thenewlevel~#}}` and `\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{}`